putImageData data doesn't adhere Clipping rule
I am trying to create a Circular QR code using Canvas API.
Here is the link to my codepen 
https://codepen.io/owner-photorush/pen/BagdWNm
So my logic is pretty much straight forward.

I take size from the input and create canvas of that size.
After That I create a Circle with radius = square /2 and apply clip so that anything outside this will not be shown.
Then I find size of maximum possible square which I can draw inside that circle where Square corners touch to Circle borders.
Then I use QR code library and put QR code inside that Square.
Then I copy center part of QR code on both horizontal and vertical angles using getImageData and put it on each side of data using putImageData.

But as you can see in the image that Clipping is not working with putImageData. I tried with other shapes functions like rect, arc which adhere the clipping rule but image is not adhering.
Current Output

Expected output should have content outside red border should be hidden.

putImageData is not a rendering function and is not affected by clip settings. It is akin to memory move (blit). If you want to clip. Move the image data to a second canvas then draw that canvas to the existing one with the clip circle.

Code should be in the question itself per the guidelines in [mcve]. Thanks.

You can create an ImageBitmap from your ImageData and then use drawImage, or you could first put your ImageData and then use composition to keep only the circle part.
